# Simple real world example where methods should not be overriden?

Tags: java

I'm preparing some exercise for the keyword final. It is use to define methods that can't be overridden in its subclasses.

But I have a problem to find some real good simple real world examples where I want to avoid that a method is overridden in the subclass.

Any hints?

Comment: If I had the time I'd `grep` the java-docs and find uses in the standard API.

Comment: The `Object.getClass()` method is final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementations of `equals()` method for not abstract classes must be marked with final modifier. This statement can be easily proved by example (real code from standard library):

```
public class Date {

     private transient long fastTime;

     ....

     public long getTime() {
         return getTimeImpl();
     }

     ....

     public boolean equals(Object obj) {
         return obj instanceof Date && getTime() == ((Date) obj).getTime();
     }
}

public class Timestamp extends java.util.Date {

    public boolean equals(java.lang.Object ts) {
        if (ts instanceof Timestamp) {
        return this.equals((Timestamp)ts);
        } else {
        return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean equals(Timestamp ts) {
        if (super.equals(ts)) {
            if  (nanos == ts.nanos) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

That means that equals() contract is violated:

```
date.equals(timestamp) == true
```

but

```
timestamp.equals(date) == false
```

Answer (score 2):

**final** methods can sometimes be inlined by the compiler into subclasses, giving a small performance benefit.

As for an example of when you would want to avoid subclasses providing their own method definitions, whenever a method's definition is is critical to the durability of the object or the performance of the system, it should be final.

Methods called from constructors should be carefully thought about, usually they need to be final to ensure a robust class definition.

Real world examples are always going to be multi-developer environments. If you work for a firm that handles credit-card information, and you have a java class that does something critical, you dont want some intern accidentally overwriting an important method, so you build the system in such a way that even other developers cant make it insecure.

Dont forget about final classes and final fields too!

Answer (score 2):

As a contrived example: you might want your class to notify observing objects that some of its state changed. You want people subclassing your class to be able to override how this state gets changed, but not that these events get sent.

```
public class Womble {
    public String fluff;

    // notify listeners that the value of 'fluff' is changing
    private void onFluffChanging() {
        //…
    }

    // Others can override this method
    protected void setFluffImpl(String value) {
        fluff = value;
    }

    // But not this one, so the notification always gets sent
    public final void setFluff(String value) {
        onFluffChanging();
        setFluffImpl(value);
    }
}
```

In general, you'd use final when you want to ensure that some behaviour of your class won't get "removed" by subclasses. Some people also prefer to use final for everything by default, to prevent any sort of unintended use of their code – the only classes and methods that are left not-final are the ones they explicitly intend to be subclassed. The latter is mostly useful when making code that will be reused a lot, and especially when making code that will be reused by inheriting its classes a lot.

Answer (score 2):

To counterbalance the other answers here--good answers, to be sure--keep in mind that in real-world use, it's often difficult to predict exactly how a class will need to be used in the future. Sprinkling `final` into your code because you feel like something shouldn't change may just be adding to the future frustration of someone using that code in a way you didn't anticipate, and `final` can always be circumvented one way or another by a creative developer. It's just a question of how much you want to tempt him/her to do so. And if it comes to that, then you better hope that person *really* knows what he or she is doing.

Answer (score 2):

There are examples in just about any framework and much library code using the [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern.

For example, in [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), many methods including `execute()` and `run()` are final, but the method `doInBackground()` called by these is abstract and intended to be defined by the subclass, while other methods have default implementations but are not final so overriding is allowed.